# 741 amplification factor doesn't change

Tags: operational-amplifier

When the positive terminal of the oscilloscope probe touches my skin, I see a 60Hz sine wave. As far as I understood this is the electromagnetic buzz coming from the AC wires in the wall and is being picked up by my body.

I can also see this wave if I grab the ADC input of my ATMEGA328 with my fingers (when the input is floating/not grounded), but it also picks up any hand movements close to it, so as far as I understood I need to ground it as well, but then the signal appears so weak when it's grounded, that the ADC is not picking it up.

I decided to try to amplify the signal with UM741, I seem to be getting a bit rounded square wave on the oscilloscope, so I believe it's working:

[image]

But now I face a problem with amplification factor:

I read that the op-amp can amplify the signal up to 80,000x and that the:

```
amplification rate = 1 + (R2/R1)
```

But when I replace the R2 with 1M resistor, I would expect for the amplification factor to jump from 2x to 27x, but the output is exactly the same.

PS: My negative input terminal on the op-amp is grounded to the power supplies negative terminal, is this correct or should it be grounded to my body since I'm taking a reading from it?

Comment: 60kHz? Shouldn't that be 60Hz?

Comment: @Andrew sorry my mistake, thanks for pointing it out, fixed

Comment: Your body probably doesn't look like a source of a constant voltage, so you're not going to get easily explicable results like this.  If you're trying to learn about op-amp gain, feed in a signal from a signal generator or an audio amplifier (headphone output on phone?)

Comment: What voltage square wave are you getting and how are you measuring it?

Comment: @WillDean thanks for the tip! the reason I'm trying to do this is so that I can attach an antenna to the input and try to pick up a radio carrier wave (I'm learning the basics, so have't yet gotten to filtering/decoding), I just though using my body as an antenna to pick up the ADC buzz from the socket would give me a similar effect, since in both cases I'm picking up the electromagnetic field. Are my assumptions correct or it does not work that way?

Comment: @Kristian You don't say what frequency of radio you're trying to pick up, but you'll probably find that a 741 is a terrible front end for that.  The front end of a radio receiver doesn't tend to look like the front end of an audio amplifier.

Comment: @Andrew I'm using HPS50 Oscilloscope with 10x probe. Negative probe is connected to the power supplies negative terminal and positive probe is connected to the op-amp's output. The output signal max peak is about 0.4v, I would like to get it up to 3v at least if possible. Thanks!

Comment: @WillDean I don't have a particular frequency as I haven't gotten that far yet, I wanted to first figure out how to amplify this AC buzz and then try to pick up the carrier wave in an particular frequency, but there are many things involved that I yet don't understand, so I'm trying to take tiny steps. Which amplifier would you suggest for an radio receiver? Thanks!

Comment: The probe ground should be connected to ground not your negative voltage rail. Also a 741 is completely inappropriate for radio signals. It may have lots of gain at low frequencies but the high frequency gain is a very different matter.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks, I will play around with this one and find a separate one for the radio receiver. Do you know why this 741 is ignoring my resistor values and the amplification rate doesn't change?

Comment: @Kristian: if you replace R2 by 6.8kOhm you get an amplification of 1 + 6.8/36 = 1.19

Comment: @Curd oh damn, thanks! idk why I had an assumption that 6k8 = 6800k. I will try using 1M resistor instead for R2

Comment: "My negative input terminal on the op-amp is grounded to the power supplies negative terminal" - surely you have it connected as per your diagram. BTW the 741 isn't recommended for supplies lower than +/- 10 volts. It's a piece of crap too!

Comment: @Andyaka I wonder whether we can have an automatism that checks for a few ancient Opamp types on question submission and automatically alerts the asker that "hey, unless you want to ask about a historic circuit..." as well as displaying an (unobtrusive, yet clearly visible block) below the question informing potential future readers that they should probably not recreate the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your schematic:

[image]

This shows a + and - supply, and the left end of R1 grounded.  But they you say:

> My negative input terminal on the op-amp is grounded to the power supplies negative terminal

There two statements contradict each other, so now we don't know what you really have connected to what.

It should be connected as your schematic shows.  You want the input signal amplified about ground, which should also be near the center of the power supply range.  The scope trace you show hints that the amp is clipping on the negative portion of the square wave:

[image]

This shows no noise ripple at the bottom level, but does at the top.

Further discussion is pointless while you're contradicting yourself.  A better answer requires a better question.